# Impact of DOM caching of pages in jquery mobile in respect to using same id's on different pages?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am new to Jquery mobile and aims to create a huge application using jquery mobile.
I found this in jquery mobile docs

The id attribute of all your elements must be not only unique on a given page, but also unique across the pages in a site. This is because jQuery Mobile's single-page navigation model allows many different "pages" to be present in the DOM at the same time. This also applies when using a multi-page template, since all "pages" on the template are loaded at once.

Also, this link [Jquery Mobile Javascript not working on ajax load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316113/jquery-mobile-javascript-not-working-on-ajax-load) suggests : using classes istead of id's to prevent this problem.

Since my current application relies a lot on ids, I felt I have to make a lot of changes to it to make it work efficiently.
But then I read this in jquery mobile docs

jQuery Mobile therefore has a simple mechanism to keep the DOM tidy. Whenever it loads a page via Ajax, jQuery Mobile flags the page to be removed from the DOM when you navigate away from it later (technically, on the pagehide event). If you revisit a removed page, the browser may be able to retrieve the page's HTML file from its cache. If not, it refetches the file from the server. (In the case of nested list views, jQuery Mobile removes all the pages that make up the nested list once you navigate to a page that's not part of the list.)

SO does that mean, if all the pages are getting loaded by ajax, I don't have to worry about using same id's on different pages since different pages won't be present in the DOM at the same time?

Also, what can be the disadvantages of loading all the pages via ajax?

This is a bit confusing for me. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

So you are going to create a huge jQuery Mobile application? This is your first mistake, when working with jQuery Mobile you need to aspire to build a lighter application. jQuery Mobile has notoriously bad performance in larger applications, specially on mobile devices. Last version brought some performance improvements but it is still not on a reasonable level.

Lets proceed, you should use unique id's when working with jQuery Mobile. It is not only a question of page id's, because everything is loaded into the DOM, if you have elements with a same id there's a good chance you will not access right content. I so this problem here so many times that it's not even funny any more. People usually don't think about this small things but if you don't take them into account from the project start you will end up in the world of pain. And trust me it is better to do something right then to massacre your code later during development.

What is not said in an official documentation, is how jQuery Mobile handles different page templates. You so/pasted how jQuery Mobile handles multi HTML page handling and that's more or less correct. What you don't know is that when working with multiple HTML files ONLY one data-role="page" is allowed per HTML file and only that div (plus it inner content), everything else is discarded. There one more thing, when working with multi page template (several pages in one HTML file), you can't programatically remove them from the DOM, everything that loads as a part of first/initial HTML file will stay in the DOM until everything is refreshed. So forget about removing those pages from the DOM, you can do that manually but then you will faces completely another set of problems.

Next thing, if you have several pages that share an id plus same inner content you will have huge problems with event binding, I can't stress you how much this is important.

Regarding your second to last question, you can use pages with same id but they need to be separated in different HTML files and you should not cache them. Only in this case old pages will get removed from the DOM and new pages will never collide with older pages sharing same ID. Still I want to advise you against this solution. Better solution would be to create/remove those pages dynamically. This way you will have much better control over your code.

Regarding your last question, more pr less, only disadvantage is application speed. But you will face much more problems if you abandon AJAX loading, of course that's completely different story.

If you want to learn what is arguably best jQuery Mobile design approach the you should read **[this](http://www.gajotres.net/secrets-of-a-good-jquery-mobile-page-architecture/)** and **[this](http://www.gajotres.net/multipage-template-vs-multi-html-template-in-jquery-mobile/)** article.