# jQuery Mobile form submission over multiple pages with CakePHP

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, jquery-mobile

I hope I am missing something simple here. I have a CakePHP web site I am using jQuery mobile with. I think CakePHP might have something to do with it, but I am not sure.

Anyway, I have a form I've created on my view page for adding comments. The Ajax call is working as expected on the first page that loads, but navigating to any other page prevents the data from being submitted. The console still logs 'data' each time I press the button (after using 'pagebeforeshow' as recommended somewhere else), however it seems to be the data from the original loaded page (I know this because I am currently debugging $this->request->data on the Form action page).

Clearly, I must need to "reset" the form somehow when moving across pages, but I am not sure if this is possible without refreshing the page. I do know about "data-ajax"="false" and "rel"="external" which can be used as a last resort, but I want to avoid refreshing the page if I can.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Here is the JS I am using for the Ajax call

```
//<![CDATA[
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function(){       
    $(document).off('click', '#comment_add').on('click', '#comment_add',function(e) {
        $.ajax({
        async:true,
        data:$("#sCommentViewForm").serialize(),
        dataType:"html",
        success:function (data, textStatus) {
            //$('#comments').remove();
            //$('<div id="comments"></div>').appendTo('#comments_container');
            $("#comments").html(data).trigger('create');
            //$('#comments_box').remove();
            //$('<div id="comments_box"></div>').appendTo('#comments_container');
            console.log(data);
        },
        type:"POST",
        url:"commentsUsers/comment_add/<? echo $template['Template']['id']; ?>"});
        return false;
    }); 
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my basic lack of understanding. After lots of searching this simple post was most helpful:

[Jquery Mobile Javascript not working on ajax load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316113/jquery-mobile-javascript-not-working-on-ajax-load)

Basically, I was using IDs for everything - when I switched to class names it was smooth sailing.